# Getting datagridview cell index in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to get Cell index after comparing values, for example i have this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[value].Value.ToString() == radTextBox1.Text)
     {
     //If the value matches how to get the row index of that
     }              
 }
```

Comment: If `value` is a string key, then you can use `...Cells[value].ColumnIndex`.

Comment: The value is the string i'm comparing. So if the text from textbox is "City" and datagrid has a cell with the value "City" get the row index for that cell

Comment: If `value` is being used as a comparison, why are you using it as a Column index?

Comment: Did you try my code? @Michael27

Comment: Your topic says you want to get Cell Index, your comment says you want row index. And you're using a loop to pass the iterator variable into the rows collection for comparison. So if the comparison is a match, wouldn't `i` be the row index at that time?

Comment: @Rekcs the Cells[value]  return the Column name, but i need value from that column. This was my mistake in code

Comment: Did you solve it then? @Michael27

Comment: Not yet. What i really need to do is compare value from the textbox and datagridview so i can get row index and you that row index to do the 
`DatagridviewRow.Selected = true;`

Comment: Is this a particular cell or is it any cell? If it's a particular cell then you need to put the cell index in place of the value. If it's any cell, then you need a nested `for loop` to move through each cell for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to find the value in any cell then you need to use a nested loop.

```
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[c].Value.ToString() == radtextBox1.Text)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;

                }
            }
        }
```

This will move through each row while checking all the columns for a value and will hilight any row where a cell has that value. Note that this code is case sensitive so "City" <> "city" but that is easily fixed using .ToUpper or .ToLower as needed.

One other thing to add, this code also is based off a DGV that has AllowUserToAddRows set to false. If you need the edit row, you either need to -1 from the count in the rows loops or check to ensure that the current row is false for .IsNewRow.

Comment: The datagridview is populated from database, it doesn't allow new Rows to be added

Comment: That's fine, just informing that there is no check for the last row being null in the code I submitted.

Comment: It for but the datagrid has 1 extra empty row, and in the empty row `if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[c].Value.ToString() == radtextBox1.Text)` gives null value and that in turn gives the `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error

EDIT, didn't see your post there

Comment: That's what the bottom of my answer talks about. You can just -1 from teh rows.count loop. `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)`

Comment: Or set `myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` 
I edited my answers, i didn't see it

Answer (score 2):

This might do the job:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == radTextBox1.Text)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You found the Row you're looking for.
It's i variable in your code.

```
var requiredRowIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[value].Value.ToString() == radTextBox1.Text)
         {
             requiredRowIndex = i; 
             break;
         }              
     }

if (requiredRowIndex != -1)
{
    // It was found.
}
else 
{
    // It was not found.
}
```

You dont show us what is the `value`? It's actualy index of Cell you're looking for.

Comment: The value is the string i'm comparing. So if the text from textbox is "City" and datagrid has a cell with the value "City" get the row index for that cell

Comment: @Michael27 you need to find row and cell indexes of string your are looking?